# How do I update the state for a single item in an array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, state

Here's a snippet of my code. It generates a table with the option to sent an email invite to each person.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state={
        persons:[],
        inviteSent: false,
    }
}

async componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({
      patients:this.props.patients,
   })
}

sendInvite = async (person) => {
        let response = ***code to send email invite***

        if(response.ok){
           this.setState({
              inviteSent: true,
           })
        }       
    }

let personList = this.props.personList
    
        let persons = personList.map((person, index)=>
            {
                return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td> 
                           {!this.state.inviteSent &&
                              <div onClick={()=>this.sendInvite(person)}>Send Invite</div>
                           }
                           {this.state.inviteSent &&
                              <div>Email Sent</div>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
             }
```

Basically, there's a button to send an email invite to each person in the table, and once sent, that specific button should disappear and be replaced by a confirmation that says 'Email Sent'. However, since the state of `inviteSent` isn't mapped to the particular person, it updates all the rows with 'Invite Sent'. How do I map it to that specific person?

Comment: I can't see any easy solution for this except for having a new property on each person called 'inviteSent'

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'inviteSent' to every person (if it possible):

```
persons:[
  {person: 'name', inviteSent: true},
  {person: 'name', inviteSent: false},
],
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this, each person already has a bunch of props. (e.g. first name, last name, email, phone, etc)

Comment: @Taco This shouldn't be a problem, you can have as many props as you like

Comment: you can change 'inviteSent' in state to array and fills it with ids of invited person (i hope every persons has id) 
```inviteSent: [1, 3, 7]``` //persons with this id invited

Comment: @WillBlack I don't follow, where would I be setting that?

Comment: @Taco Where are you reading your list from currently? I.e. this.props.personList

Comment: @Trebblez it's getting them from the database, but I can't add a new field there for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the list of persons in the state, each having an own „inviteSent“ Attribute. When an invite was sent to one person, you have to find the person in the list which shall be updated. This can be achieved for example using the array method „map“ which allows to iterate over an array to find the one item meeting a specific condition for example a person with a certain id.